# Шифр Цезаря на Python

Tags: python

не могу понять, что не так с кодом. Вроде бы всё работает, но задание на сайте его не принимает. Задание звучит так "Юлий Цезарь использовал шифрование текста. Каждая буква менялась на следующую по алфавиту через k позиций по кругу. Необходимо по заданному шифру установить исходный текст

Вводные данные: В первой строке задано шифровку, которая состоит из не более 255 больших латинских букв. Во второй строке число k (1 ≤ k ≤ 10).

Исходные данные: результат шифра

Например: вводите XPSE
1
Получаете: WORD

[Ссылка на задание](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/2164)

Вот мой код :

```
import string

s = input()
n = int(input())
alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
for l in s:
    k = alpha.index(l)
    k -= n
    s = s.replace(l, alpha[k])
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать `replace` с исходной строкой, потому что вы меняете какую-то букву на другую, и если потом такая же буква как эта новая встретится в исходном слове, то вы эту поменянную уже букву сдвинете **ещё раз**. Лучше для таких операций использовать, например, *списковое сокращение* (либо простое добавление в список в цикле), чтобы обрабатывать буквы слова **независимо друг от друга**. Например, запустите ваш код и введите `ZYX`, результат будет `WWW` именно из-за вышеописанного.

P.S. По двум другим пунктам я был не прав, не обратил внимание, что речь о **расшифровке** шифра. Убрал их.

Comment: По первому пункту вы не правы. В файле зашифрованный текст сдвинутый вперёд, так что для расшифровки действительно надо вычитать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Упс. Значит только третий пункт действителен

Comment: Тут нужно вычитать. Спасибо большое, очень помогли. Без replace получилось. Я просто создал новый массив с нужными мне данными и вывел их в срочку через цикл for

Comment: @nikitasokolov Список букв можно склеить обратно в строку через `''.join(lst)`, если что

Answer (score 0):

ошибка в том, что alpha.index(l) возвращает номер буквы в строке, что тебе не нужно, тебе нужно исспользовать функции ord и chr, для кирилицы предварительно импортировать модуль unicodedata. Решение не прилагаю, так как отберу интерес. Так же следует учесть, что наборы символов содержат знаки препинания, что не вписывается в класическое решение. Так же следует учесть цикличность, к примеру к последней букве нужно добавить число (нужно будет считать с начала).

Comment: По условию задания в строке только 26 заглавных латинских букв. Так что из всех трудностей тут только не забыть переход через границу

Comment: Был не внимателен, тогда моуль string, чтобы не писать алфавит. И вроде бы в моуле this исспользуется этот же алгоритм.